# Cannot Implicity convert type of an object to an system.collection.generic.IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net

> Error  CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'Vidly.Models.HotelInformation' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Vidly.Models.HotelInformation>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I am receiving this error when running my application. I have written

```
Hotel = new HotelInformation()
```

(where I am receiving the error)

In my view model I am writing

```
public IEnumerable<HotelInformation> Hotel { get; set; }
```

I've looked at other solutions, but they didn't seem to work.

Comment: "when running my application. I have written" - it's not enaugh to answer it. MVC exists not only in one technology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your property is of type `IEnumerable<HotelInformation>`.  But you are trying to set it to a value of type `HotelInformation`.  As the error states, the types are different.

If you want to set the property to a list, create it as a new list.  Something like:

```
Hotel = new List<HotelInformation>();
```

Conversely, if you want to set to a single instance of `HotelInformation` then make the property that type:

```
public HotelInformation Hotel { get; set; }
```

Which solution you *should* use is up to you and what you want that property to be.  (Though its *name* implies that it should be a single instance.)

Comment: Seriously, thank you so much! I've been stuck on that for a while, although now it seems obvious.